# Checks if a value exists in an array input value by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want check if id in array value input:cheched `3`, `alert (true)` else `alert (false)`. I tried as following js code, but don't work for me.

How can fix it?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VAwHR/4/

**HTML:**

```
<input value="3" type="text" id="seeid">
<div class="paginate">
    <input name="ch[]" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
    <input name="ch[]" type="checkbox" value="2">
    <input name="ch[]" type="checkbox" value="3" checked>
    <input name="ch[]" type="checkbox" value="4">
</div>
<input type="submit" class="sub">
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.sub').click(function(){
    var seeid = $('#seeid').val();
    var db = $('.paginate :checkbox:checked').map(function (i, n) {
        return $(n).val();
    }).get();
    alert($.inArray(seeid, db))
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two errors. The first:

```
<input value="3" type="text" id="#seeid"> // id should be "seed"
```

The second:

```
$.inArray(seeid, db) > 0
```

should be

```
$.inArray(seeid, db) > -1 // or ~$.inArray(seeid, db)
```

Your code will fail to detect value 1 for example, because `indexOf` will return 0 in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the problem in `id` place you are having `#`

```
<input value="3" type="text" id="#seeid">
```

use this

```
<input value="3" type="text" id="seeid">
```

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, But still it does not work for me:http://jsfiddle.net/VAwHR/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sub').click(function(){
  var seeid = $('#seeid').val();

  var db = $('.paginate :checkbox:checked').map(function (i, n) {
    return $(n).val();
  }).get();

  var flag;
  if(flag = $.inArray(seeid, db) > -1){
    alert(flag);   
  }
  else {
    alert(flag);   
  }
})
```

paste this into fiddle - it should give you the correct true/false alerts